# DB field empty problems in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a method in `Spring Boot` that collects various database dates from the logged in employee.

```
private boolean isActiveThisMonth(EmployeeView emp,LocalDate date){
        return (emp.getHiringDate().withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1).isBefore(date.withDayOfMonth(1)) && (emp.getLeavingDate()==null ||
                emp.getLeavingDate().plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1).isAfter(date.with(lastDayOfMonth()))));
    }
```

Currently if the `hiringDate` field is empty in the database, it returns an error. How can I add an exception so that if the field arrives without an error? Or if it is better to put a date, for example the current day and thus not an error?

Comment: The question is really, what do you want it to do if there is no hiring date? Can you live with a default value? Do you want it to tell you that it didn't find a date without throwing an error? Once you know how you want to handle the case, you can either set a default or catch and transform the error.

Comment: In case of not finding the hiring date that returns the current day by default and thus not cause a null error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways to prevent this.

1.

You could handle the null value inside `isActiveThisMonth` like this

```
private boolean isActiveThisMonth(EmployeeView emp,LocalDate date){
    LocalDate hiringDate = emp.getHiringDate() != null ? emp.getHiringDate() : LocalDate.now();
    return (hiringDate.withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1).isBefore(date.withDayOfMonth(1)) && (emp.getLeavingDate()==null ||
            emp.getLeavingDate().plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1).isAfter(date.with(lastDayOfMonth()))));
}
```

2. 

You could make sure the value is set in the Entity when the Employee is created.

```
  @Column(name = "hire_date", columnDefinition = "DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE")
  private jDate startDate;
```